# How can I find where a tombstone file is pointing to?

Tags: sql-server, ntfs, windows-home-server

I'm installing SQL Server on Windows Home Server. It failed.  It think it is because when it load the master DB it doesn't understand NTFS tombstones--the windows event log seems to think the system has an E: drive and there isn't.

Do any commands exist to check to see if file is a tombstone and where the real file is being held?

Answer (score 1):

If these tombstones are in fact NTFS reparse points or junctions, you might want to try one of the tools mentioned in this KB article:
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/205524

There's also sysinternals (well, Microsoft) tool called Junction that might help: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896768.aspx

Comment: `Junction` will show 'UNKNOWN MICROSOFT REPARSE POINT' if the drive is missing (I have Windows Home Server and I'm pulling out each drive in turn and see this for every file)